# Creating a function to save different columns from a list into a dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to look into a dataset using a forloop. The data contains lists and I'm trying to create a function which saves the output of the loop into a dataframe. It is something similar to this example

```
test = function(inputname) { 
    if(is_empty(obs$company$inputname[[1]])){
        data[[i]] = obs
    } else {
        data[[i]] = obs$company %>%
        unnest(inputname)
    }
    df_inputname = data %>% 
        rbindlist(fill = TRUE) %>% 
        select(company:date)
}

test(address)
```

Im trying to get this to return a dataframe called 'df_address' containing information from the `input_name = address` from the list in the data. But i get an error messasage saying that the column doesnt exists. The idea is I can look up different variables within the list and save the results as a dataframe. Ideally I would want to be able to search for multiple variables and add them into a dataframe, but in this first go Im simply annoyed as why I ge tthe error. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your dataset (or list) actually an object called `data`? Are you creating it yourself from scratch in the function? You've referenced a number of objects like `data` and `obs` that aren't defined as inputs into your function. Might be easier to help if you provide us with those objects as well.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems, and it seems your function is having issues with whatever data you are using. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg